# the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I try calculate differences of 2 column table and save in another. But all the time i have error "the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer". Someone can expalin me what am I doing wrong?

This is my Code

```
 public ActionResult Index(Timesheet timeLogger)
    {
        System.DateTime momentStart = new System.DateTime();
        System.DateTime momentEnd = new System.DateTime();
        Nullable < System.DateTime > b;
        int a=0;
        timeLogger.EndWork =  momentEnd;
        timeLogger.StartWork = momentStart;
        timeLogger.TotalTime=a;

        int houerEnd = momentEnd.Hour;
        int houerStart = momentStart.Hour;

        houerEnd - houerStart = a;

        return View();
    }
```

Model class

enter code here

Comment: `houerEnd - houerStart = a;` ... try `a = houerEnd - houerStart;` ?

Comment: I tried but nothing changes.

Comment: `Nullable < System.DateTime > b;` what are you trying to accomplish with this line?

Comment: I restart my PC and first idea is good. Thank you. Nullable < System.DateTime > b;---i forgot remove.